# Android : How to regain focus of edit text inside header item of expendable list view?

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

I have `expendableList` view with custom header view. Header view contains an `EditText`. Expendable list expend feature works only when I set `editText#focus ="false"` but how to gain focus of edit text again for typing some value?
Here is my `expendableList`:

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/keywordList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
 />
```

Here is my header's `editText` :

```
<EditText
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:textSize="@dimen/ts_normal"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etKeyword"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorControlNormalHalf"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edit_cursor_layout"
            android:hint="Insert Keyword"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set requestFocus, when change of text occurs :

```
etKeyword.requestFocus();
```